# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am coding a hangman game and this line of code gives me errors.

```
print (str+"You have") + turns (str+"more guesses")
```

I do not know what to do or how to resolve it.

```
print (str+"You have") + turns (str+"more guesses")  
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'str'
```

Comment: `str` is a type, why are you trying to add it with `"You have"`? Just remove it.

Comment: Also, you'll get another error afterwards because `print` returns `None` which you can't concatenate with whatever `turns` is.

Comment: What you are trying to do is called "casting".  This converts one type to another.  eg:  converting an integer value of 1 to the string value of "1". google "python casting". As was already mentioned you don't need to cast but reading up on it will tell you why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you were going for, but this should fix most of it:

```
print('You have ' + turns + ' more guesses')
```

no need to use `str` for stuff like this and don't use `+` outside the parenthesis of `print()`

This assumes your `turns` variable is a string, but if it is a number it should be:

```
print('You have ' + str(turns) + ' more guesses')
```